# what to use in place of mrunit withInputValue deprecated

Tags: hadoop, mrunit

I am using MRUnit to test Map Reduce code. I can't use .withInputValue as it is deprecated. 
I could not locate an equivalent that works. setInputValue does not work either. What is the work-around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `withInput()`. Exmaple (this. is with mrunit-1.0.0-hadoop2.jar )

```
MapDriver<LongWritable,Text,Text,IntWritable> mapDriver;
...
mapDriver.withInput(new LongWritable(), new Text("some line of text));
mapDriver.withOUtput(new Text("some key)); new IntWritable(..));
mapDriver.runTest();
```

Here's the maven dependency. Note the Hadoop2 classifier.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.mrunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>mrunit</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <classifier>hadoop2</classifier>
</dependency>
```

For more info, see the [tutorial](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MRUNIT/MRUnit+Tutorial)